# How to detect modified buffer in the mode-line, skipping special buffers?

Tags: mode-line, buffer-modified

I'm trying to have my mode-line to display a "(modified)" string instead of the `*` mark. To do that, I make a test with `buffer-modified-p` but this seems to be always true for "special" buffers as well (such as for example completion list or org agenda). What would be the proper way to do the test (i.e. files that have been modified by me) ? Here is the relevant part of my code: `'(:eval (if (buffer-modified-p) "%b (modified)" "%b"))`

**Solution**:

```
'(:eval (if (and (or buffer-file-name
                    (string= (buffer-name) "*scracth*"))
                 (buffer-modified-p))
            "%b (modified)" "%b"))
```

Comment: Perhaps, you want `(and buffer-file-name (buffer-modified-p))` as test?

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick.

Comment: But it does not work with the "*scracth*" buffer

Comment: That depends what you want with the scratch buffer. It is (normally) not associated with a file. So do you want to have the modification notification there?

Comment: Ideally yes, but that's not a big deal if I cannot. I guess I can add a specific `(eq buffer-name "*scratch*")` for this special case.

Comment: Yes, or `(derived-mode-p 'lisp-interaction-mode)` if you want to allow multiple scratch buffers.

Comment: My scratch buffer is in text mode. I just discovered that `buffer-name` seems to be empty for the scratch buffer. This is weird since I'm able to display it using the `%b` construct.

Comment: `(buffer-name)` should work.

Comment: This `(if (eq (buffer-name) "*scratch*") (message "true") (message "false"))` evalutes to false in the scratch buffer. I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Stupid errorr: `string=` not `eq`.